# Pushing/Presenting ViewController from Separated UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a ticketsVC that has a segmentedControl that toggles two tableViews (a upcomingTableView and a pastTransactionsTableView). These two tableViews are created on separate files. I would like to push/present a new VC from the tableViews but unfortunately I cannot access navigationController or presentVC from these tableViews.

My approach as such:

```
class TicketsViewController: UIViewController {

   let segmentedControllerView: SegmentedController = {
        let sc = SegmentedController()
        sc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        sc.segmentedController.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentedControlValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
        sc.segmentedController.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        return sc
    }()

    let upcomingTableView: UpcomingTableView = {
        let tv = UpcomingTableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tv
    }()

    let pastTransactionsTableView: PastTransactionsTableView = {
        let tv = PastTransactionsTableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tv
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //setupNavigationBar()
        //setupViews()
    }

    @objc func segmentedControlValueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        let segmentedControl = sender

        if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            upcomingTableView.isHidden = false
            pastTransactionsTableView.isHidden = true
        } else {
            upcomingTableView.isHidden = true
            pastTransactionsTableView.isHidden = false
        }
    }

//Both UpcomingTableView and PastTransactionsTableView
//are created similar as below
class UpcomingTableView: UITableView {

    override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableViewStyle) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: style)

        delegate = self
        dataSource = self

        register(CustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

extension UpcomingTableView: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    //all the neccessary dataSource and delegate functions

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = TicketsViewController()
        vc.present(UIViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
        //This method cannot access TicketsVC
    }
}
```

My reason for adopting this approach is that both upcomingTableView and pastTransactionsTableView shows very different cells and pulls separate models. Does anyone have any advice how may I push/present a new VC from these tableViews itself?

Comment: just use didselect method and inside it add code to present new VC

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar I can't access `navigationController?.pushViewController()` or `present` from the `didSelect` method

Comment: Check with self.presenting view

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar I have already checked, the method is not accessible.

Comment: you should be able to use it How you are using it plz paste the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, I would do it like this:
In **ticketsVC** create a segmented control and position it to the top. Then add a simple UIView below which we will use as a container for tables. It should look like this in Storyboard:

[image]

I prefer to keep UITableView inside the UIViewController because I always have something else inside.
Now create two UIViewControllers and add a UITableView in each and do everything you need to do related to tables in these two UIViewControllers.

```
    class SampleOneVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
// Your code for table 1
}

    class SampleTwoVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
// Your code for table 2
}
```

Create an extension for UIViewController:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func configureChildViewController(childController: UIViewController, onView: UIView?) {
        var holderView = self.view
        if let onView = onView {
            holderView = onView
        }
        addChildViewController(childController)
        holderView!.addSubview(childController.view)
        constrainViewEqual(holderView: holderView!, view: childController.view)
        childController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }


    func constrainViewEqual(holderView: UIView, view: UIView) {
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let pinTop = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: holderView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let pinBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: holderView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let pinLeft = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .left, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: holderView, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
        let pinRight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: view, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: holderView, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

        holderView.addConstraints([pinTop, pinBottom, pinLeft, pinRight])
    }
}
```

Now go back to ticketsVC and declare variables

```
var sampleOneVC: UIViewController!
var sampleTwoVC: UIViewController!
```

Initialize them in ViewDidLoad

```
// Don't forget to set the IDs in storyboard (Identity Inspector tab) for view controllers 
// field: 'Storyboard ID' 
// values: SampleOneVC & SampleTwoVC
sampleOneVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SampleOneVC") as! SampleOneVC
sampleTwoVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SampleTwoVC") as! SampleTwoVC
```

Now in `segmentedControlValueChanged` update the presented view controller

```
self.configureChildViewController(childController: sampleOneVC, onView: myContainerView)
```

Now you should be able to use segues inside the `didSelectRowAt` in SampleOneVC and SampleTwoVC. I didn't write the whole code, but I hope you have the idea how it can be done another way.

Comment: Thanks! I've created a separate project to test out your code and it works exactly how I wanted.

Comment: Just one question, I would like to ask if it is necessary to do `childController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)`. Functionally it works correctly even without this line. I just wanna understand the purpose.

Comment: I always use it when I add viewController to a container. To be honest, didn't try without that. :) [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621405-didmove) is the documentation so you can understand it better.